# Data Loss during write back using sokcet programming

Tags: c++, http, sockets

Currently, I'm learning how to build a transparent HTTP proxy in C++. There had two issues on the proxy client side I couldn't resolve for long time. Hope someone can point out the root causes based on following scenarios. Thanks a lot. :D

The HTTP proxy I built right now is somehow work partially only. For example, I could access google's main page through proxy while I couldn't get any search result after I typed keyword(the google instant is also not working at all). On the other hand, youtube is working perfectly includes searching, loading video and commenting. What's more, there also got some websites like yahoo even couldn't display main page after I keyed in its URL.

The reason why I said the issues are on the proxy client side at the begining is because I traced the data flow of my program. I found out the written size returned by socket programming function write() was smaller than the data size I passed to my write back function. The most weird observation for me was the data losing issue is independent from the size of data. The socket write() function could work properly for youtube video data which is nearly 2MB while it would loss data for google search request which is just 20KB.

Furthermore, there also had another situation that browser displayed blank when the data size I passed to my write back function and the written size returned by socket write function() are the same. I used wireshark to trace the flow of communication and compared mine with pure IP communication without proxy involved. I found out that browser didn't continuously send out HTTP requests after it received certain HTTP responses comparing with pure IP communication flow. I couldn't find out why the browser didn't send out rest of HTTP requests.

Following is my code for write back function:

```
void Proxy::get_data(char* buffer, size_t length)
{
    cout<<"Length:"<<length<<endl;

    int connfd;
    size_t ret;

    // get connfd from buffer
    memset(&connfd, 0, sizeof(int));
    memcpy(&connfd, buffer, sizeof(int));
    cout<<"Get Connection FD:"<<connfd<<endl; 

    // get receive data size
    size_t rData_length = length-sizeof(int);
    cout<<"Data Size:"<<rData_length<<endl;
    // create receive buffer
    char* rBuf = new char[rData_length];
    // allocate memory to receive buffer
    memset(rBuf, 0, rData_length);
    // copy data to buffer
    memcpy(rBuf, buffer+sizeof(int), rData_length);

    ret = write(connfd, rBuf, rData_length);

    if(ret < 0)
    {
        cout<< "received data failed"<< endl;
        close(connfd);
        delete[] rBuf;
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Write Data[%d] to Socket\n", ret); 
    }

    close(connfd);
    delete[] rBuf;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you could try this

```
int curr = 0;
while( curr < rData_length ) {
    ret = write( connfd, rBuf + curr, rData_length - curr );
    if( ret == -1 ) { /* ERROR */ }
    else
        curr += ret;
}
```

instead of

```
ret = write(connfd, rBuf, rData_length);
```

In general, the number of bytes written by `write()` could differ from what you ask to write. You should better read some manual. Say, http://linux.die.net/man/2/write

Comment: Shamdor, thanks to your reply. I have read write() function and wrote the while loop for continuously writing back. However, every time I just received a -1 error. At the beginning, I thought the error was due to I write back too fast so that I added sleep() function into. The results still showed -1 error.

Comment: Try to print the errno value every time you get -1. It should give a hint.

Answer (score 0):

Copying bytes between an input socket and an output socket is much simpler than this. You don't need to dynamically allocate buffers according to how much data was read by the last read. You just need to read into a char[] array and write from that array to the target, taking due account of the length value returned by the read.

Comment: EJP, thanks to your reply. I have tag one connection FD in front of the data and that's the reason why I need to temporary buffer to separate and hold them respectively. My HTTP proxy client and server are two different subsystem and I tried to integrate the HTTP proxy with delay tolerant networks(DTN) so that I can't directly read then write back.